# how to get grand total dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have dropdown of nationality with its related price for rooms of hotel.Now I want to dynamically add the prices shown and output it.

```
<div class="Total"></div>
<div class="rum_name">Room name</div>
<div class="nationality">
<select class="sel_nationality" name="nationality">
<option roomprice="30" value="63">SAARC</option>
<option roomprice="50" selected="selected" value="65">American/ European</option>
<option roomprice="45" value="67">Japnese/ Korean</option>
<option roomprice="38" value="69">All Others</option>
</select>
<div class="Price">
Price:
<span class="selectedPrice"></span>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.sel_nationality').change(function(){
            $price = $('option:selected', this).attr('roomprice');
            $parent = $(this).parents('.nationality');
            $parent.find('span.selectedPrice').text($price);
            $tot_price = $(this).val();
            $(this).each(function(){
                total += parseInt(this.value);
            })
           $('.Total').text(total); 
        })
           })
</script>
```

There may be more than 1 rooms and the above option for each.Now I want to dynamically change the total as perthe price outputted.
Thanks

Comment: Please use parseInt(val,10). I mean radix 10 !!!

Comment: @Murali cant quite catch you.Can you please elaborate.

Comment: What are you saying Sammy, it's working for one room but not for multiple rooms?

Comment: @sammy please see http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-parseint-08-returns-0/ .This is a small correction to your code and it is not an answer for your question

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot i have multiple rooms with different price for nationlity.Now for the number of nationality selected in dropdown I want the Grand Total to be displayed somewhere in same page.Problem is whenever I change the option twice instead of taking the value of selected only it is summing up with previous total,so i am getting wrong total.

Comment: Try moving `var total = 0` down one line so it's inside the change handler

Comment: I'm fascinated. In which country is it legal to set the charge for a room (or anything else) depending on the customer's nationality? Remind me never to go there.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot sorry if it offended you,not my intention but during site visits the price for saarc countries, local and international differ and its just that i wanted to implement the same idea.

Comment: In Europe the hotel owner would receive a serious fine.

Comment: And please, there's no need to apologize. You are not responsible for the laws, or their failings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well guys i think i am not able to give you the correct idea of my problem, but i found the solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.selectedPrice').each(function(){
            total = +$(this).text()+ total;
        });
        $('.Total').text(total); 
        $('.sel_nationality').change(function(){
            $price = $('option:selected', this).attr('roomprice');
            $parent = $(this).parents('.nationality');
            $parent.find('span.selectedPrice').text($price);
            var total = 0;
            $('.selectedPrice').each(function(){
                total = +$(this).text()+ total;
            });
           $('.Total').text(total); 

        })


    })
</script>
```

anyways THANK YOU guys for your valuable time and SORRY if i wasnt able to give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sammy I think you will find that your solution simplifies to this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sel_nationality').change(function() {
        var $price = $('option:selected', this).attr('roomprice');//remember to localize vars
        $(this).closest('.nationality').find('.selectedPrice').text($price);
        var total = 0;
        $('.selectedPrice').each(function() {
            total += Number($(this).text());
        });
        $('.Total').text(total);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

By triggering the select menus' 'change' events, you will avoid the need to repeat the total calculation and cause the initially selected prices to be displayed.

Comment: thanks for posting got to know about new things.For a newbie like me it's very munch helpful and knowledgeble.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the total on each change, otherwise it will just keep adding up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sel_nationality').on('change', function() {
        var total = 0,  //reset the total, notice commas declearing vars
            $price = $('option:selected', this).attr('roomprice'),
            $parent = $(this).parents('.nationality'),
            $tot_price = this.value;

        $parent.find('span.selectedPrice').text($price);

        $('.sel_nationality').each(function() { //iterate all, not just this one
            total += parseInt(this.value, 10);  //use radix
        });
        $('.Total').text(total);
    });
})​;​
```

You need to iterate over all the `.sel_nationality` elements, not just `this`, as that would'nt really need an each loop, and declear the variables, as if you don't, they will be global, does'nt matter if they start with a dollarsign, they should still be decleared with the `var` keyword.

As a sidenote, `roomprice` is not a valid attribute, and HTML5 data attributes would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sel_nationality').change(function(){
        var total = 0; //let the total be 0 whenever the chnages is made
        $price = $('option:selected', this).attr('roomprice');
        $parent = $(this).parents('.nationality');
        $parent.find('span.selectedPrice').text($price);
        $tot_price = $(this).val();
        $(this).each(function(){
            total += parseInt(this.value);
        })
       $('.Total').text(total); 
    })
  })
```